# I'm trying to display radio buttons using a rails form and there not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails and I'm trying to create a basic form to post a job. I'm trying to add a radio button section where a user can choose a job type. But the issue I'm facing is that my radio buttons aren't showing when I view my view via localhost:3000

Here is my form:

```
<div class="card border-secondary mb-3">
<div class="card-body">

<%= form_with(model: job, local: true) do |form| %>
<% if job.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(job.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this job from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% job.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= form.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Job Title' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= form.text_field :company_name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Company Name'  %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= form.text_field :location, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Job Location (If job is remote. Fill in with Remote)'  %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= form.text_field :website, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Company Website' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= form.text_field :salary_range, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Salary Range'  %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= form.text_field :apply_link, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Link Where to Apply'  %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= form.hidden_field :details, class: 'form-control', id: :post_body %>
  <trix-editor input="post_body", placeholder="Job discription"></trix-editor>
  </div><br>

   <div class="form-group">
   <h4>Job type:</h4>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
   <%= form.radio_button :employment_type, 'Full-time' %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <label>
    <span class="job-listing-radio-label-styles">Full Time</span>  Salary position, typically 40-hour work weeks, often including benefits
   </label>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
   <%= form.radio_button :employment_type, 'Part-Time' %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <label>
    <span class="job-listing-radio-label-styles">Part Time</span>  Hourly position, typically 35-hour work weeks or less
   </label>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
   <%= form.radio_button :employment_type, 'Freelance' %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <label>
    <span class="job-listing-radio-label-styles">Freelance</span>  One-off projects, typically offsite with variable timeframes
   </label>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
   <%= form.radio_button :employment_type, 'Contract' %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <label>
    <span class="job-listing-radio-label-styles">Contract</span>  One-off projects or recurring work, typically 40-hour work weeks
   </label>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
   <%= form.radio_button :employment_type, 'Internship' %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <label>
    <span class="job-listing-radio-label-styles">Internship</span> Paid or unpaid, full or part time, typically leading to full time employment
   </label>
   </div>

   <hr>

   <div class="form-group">
   <%= form.radio_button :remote_type, 'Yes' %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <label>
    <span class="job-listing-radio-label-styles">Yes</span>  This job accepts remote applications
   </label>
   </div>

   <hr>

   <div class="field-group">
   <h4>Jobs Category</h4>
   <%= form.select(:job_category_id, options_for_select(@job_categories), {}, class: 'custom-select') %>
   </div><br>

   <div class="actions">
   <%= form.submit "Create New Job Posting", class: 'btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg', style: 'font-size:18px;' %>
   </div>
    <% end %>

   </div><!-- End .card-body -->
   </div><!-- End .card -->
```

Why do you think they aren't showing?

Thank you so much ahead of time! (If you need me to delete parts of the form because it's not needed for the question, just ask :) )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put your radio buttons inside label tags.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>
     <%= form.radio_button :employment_type, 'Full-time' %>
     <span class="job-listing-radio-label-styles">Full Time</span>  Salary position, typically 40-hour work weeks, often including benefits
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: then problem is with your span tag. Remove that span tag and test.